# Как максимально быстро проверить, существует ли локальный файл?

Tags: php

Нужно БЫСТРО проверить имеется ли локальный php-файл на сервере. Замеряю время выполнения скрипта.

```
Способ с file_exists  - ~0.08сек
Способ с @get_headers - ~0.3сек
```

Есть ли способы проверить существование файла быстрее?

Если файл существует я его include-ю. Конечно можно совсем не проверять, а сразу инклюдить (вывод ошибок отключен), но этот способ мне не нравится.

Comment: Может быть, не проверять существование, а инклюдить по списку существующий файлов по заданным критериям, как это обычно делаю?

Comment: А что значит по заданным критериям? Я знаю имя файла, который нужно инклюдить. Все. Других критериев нет.

Comment: Обычно практикуют названия файлов для подключения определенным стилем, например Model_User.php и программа которая автоматом подгружает классы знает как это сделать. Вопрос, какие имена у ваших файлов? что в них, подпрограммы или классы? Если классы используйте `__autoload`

Comment: Там код генерящий html

Comment: Конечная цель какая? Распишите задачу подробнее. Не вот эту, с файлом, а ту, для которой вам этот изврат понадобился. Вопрос из категории "у меня штаны на голову не налезают, как лучше, в правую штанину лезть или в левую?"

Comment: Оценил юмор. ))) Основной скрипт генерит карточку товара ИМ. После того как было все написано и база товаров готова выяснилось, что нужно добавить еще один раздел в карточку товара. Данные для этого раздела представлены в виде кучи текстовых файлов. Чтобы быстро решить вопрос использую includе. Имена файлов - это артикульный номер товара. У части товаров эти данные отсутствуют.

Comment: Может перегнать в базу текстовую информацию? Если описание одного товара состоит из нескольких, то склеить и запихнуть уже подготовленную информацию.

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного для человека с интеллектом. (с)... Однако в контексте вопроса давайте считать что это невозможно.

Comment: Тут думаю либо быстро писать код, либо быстро обрабатывать файлы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Вы же понимаете что данный тест для 100000 итераций. Сколько у вас будет файлов? И сколько понадобится оперативки для них?
> 2. Помним же за приставку include**_once**?
> 3. Про работу OPCache и APCCache тоже думаю
> 4. И чем чреват **realpath**

```
define('FILE_CHECK',  __DIR__ . '/config/common/mysql/production.php');
define('ITERATION', 100000);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    file_exists(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nFileExists:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    is_file(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nIsFile:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    filesize(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nFileSize:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    fileperms(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nFilePermission:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    fileinode(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nFileINode:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    @require(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nRequire:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    @require_once(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nIncludeOnce:" . (microtime(true) - $start);


$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    @include(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nInclude:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
    @include_once(FILE_CHECK);
}
echo "\nIncludeOnce:" . (microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ITERATION; $i++) {
}
echo "\nEmptyLoop:" . (microtime(true) - $start);
```

Comment: А можно ли в общих чертах обрисовать по подробнее то что вы упомянули в ответе под номерами 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: Проверил предлагаемые первые 4 способа, они примерно сравнимы. Остальное у меня не работает, либо не знаю как применить.

Comment: Не работает скорее всего, потому что вы под Windows работаете или подключаете классы или функции. Расскажу я вам одну TrueStory. Дабы убедить таки перейти на хранилище. Как-то мне попался кусок кода который выполнял подобные действия, и скорее всего был быстрым решением проблемы, вместо подключения компонента с БД. Но через какое-то время он начал обрастать функционалом как снежный ком. И поверьте это была дичь.  Там были и функции для поиска по тексту в файлах, и фильтры и сортировка. Сжальтесь над людьми которые будут это поддерживать.

Comment: Вы безусловно правы.

Comment: есть `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` неплохая константа :)

Comment: @Naumov. К чему про сепаратор? Если касательно обвеса над realpath, то согласен, но на практике еще ни разу не столкнулся с таким. Если касательно того что может где-то что-то не работать, то это разве что наоборот для backslash. Windows понимает оба разделителя, достаточно использовать в коде разделитель Linux вместо константы.